# How to read common table from multiple SQL databases in R

Tags: r, sqlite

I have multiple sqlite databases and would like to extract a common table (named "Sound Acquisition") without reading in all the tables of the database.
I know this can be done going through each sql database, extracting all tables, and selecting the one I want as a data frame, but there must be a more efficient way to do this...I have 15 .sqlite3 files.

Here's what I've tried.

```
SQL_files <- list.files(path = "PARENT_PATH", pattern = ".sqlite3", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE) 

SQL <- NA

for(i in 1:length(SQL_files)) {
  SQL <-  DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname= SQL_files[i])
}

tables <- dbListTables(SQL)
tables <- tables[tables != "sqlite_sequence"]

#see table names
tables 

#Sound Acquisition table
tables[[16]]

# create a data.frame for the table I want
lDataFrame <- dbGetQuery(conn=SQL, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", tables[[16]], "'", sep=""))
```

One thing I noticed here is that the data is incomplete and this is because the index for the table I want is not always the same. From a SQL layman point of view, searching for the actual name would be more logic, but I haven't found a way to do this and implement it correctly...

`df <- tbl(SQL, from = 'Sound_Acquisition')`

This also gives wrong values, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: What does it mean to "extract a common table"? Is the problem that you have 15 sqlite databases, each with a table named "sqlite_sequence" having the same column names and you want to create an R data.frame that contains all rows of all 15 tables?

Comment: My sqlite databases have a common table called "Sound_Acquisition", with multiple columns.The Sqlite databases have many other tables that I am not interested in, as I really only want to extract only that single table from each. Then, once all "Sound_Acquisition" tables are extracted, I want to merge them in a data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting to a database does not read in the tables and since the name of the table is the same in all databases just refer to its name.

Below we use the test data generated in the Note at the end.  BOD is a built-in data frame containing 6 rows.

The fn$ prefacing Map in the code below converts the formula in the arguments to `Map` to a function having `db` (the only free variable) as an argument.  We could have used  `function(db) ...whatever...` instead.

```
library(data.table)
library(sqldf)

L <- fn$Map(~ sqldf("select * from Sound_Acquisition", dbname = db), SQL_files)
rbindlist(L, idcol = "db")
```

giving:

```
           db Time demand
 1: aa.sqlite    1    8.3
 2: aa.sqlite    2   10.3
 3: aa.sqlite    3   19.0
 4: aa.sqlite    4   16.0
 5: aa.sqlite    5   15.6
 6: aa.sqlite    7   19.8
 7: bb.sqlite    2   16.6
 8: bb.sqlite    4   20.6
 9: bb.sqlite    6   38.0
10: bb.sqlite    8   32.0
11: bb.sqlite   10   31.2
12: bb.sqlite   14   39.6
13: cc.sqlite    3   24.9
14: cc.sqlite    6   30.9
15: cc.sqlite    9   57.0
16: cc.sqlite   12   48.0
17: cc.sqlite   15   46.8
18: cc.sqlite   21   59.4
```

### Note

Create test databases:

```
library(RSQLite)

SQL_files <- c("aa.sqlite", "bb.sqlite", "cc.sqlite")
i <- 1
for(i in seq_along(SQL_files)) {
  con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), SQL_files[i])
  dbWriteTable(con, "Sound_Acquisition", i * BOD)
  dbDisconnect(con)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have `dbConnect` in the loop. Running this as a script will only query data from the last data base set in the loop.

Can you try something like this (not tested!)

```
SQL_files <- list.files(path = "PARENT_PATH", pattern = ".sqlite3", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE) 

SQL <- NA
lDataFrame <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(SQL_files)) {
  SQL <-  DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname= SQL_files[i])


tables <- dbListTables(SQL)
tables <- tables[tables != "sqlite_sequence"]

#see table names
tables 

#Sound Acquisition table
tables[[16]]

# create a data.frame for the table I want
data <- dbGetQuery(conn=SQL, statement=paste("SELECT * FROM '", tables[[16]], "'", sep=""))

lDataFrame <- rbind(lDataFrame, data)

}
```

Comment: Gives me "Error in tables[[16]] : subscript out of bounds". I actually start to think that for this I need to write a function where the input is the sqlite databases and the table name, and then run the function inside a loop... ```dur.df <- function(SQL, table) {

  tst <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname= SQL) 
  df <- tbl(tst, from = table)
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  
  df$origin <- rep(SQL, nrow(df))
  
  return(df)
} ``

Comment: Could not finish my edit...
´dur.df <- function(SQL, table) {
  tst <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname= SQL) 
  df <- tbl(tst, from = table)
  df <- as.data.frame(df)
  df$origin <- rep(SQL, nrow(df))
  return(df)
}         

df1 <- dur.df(SQL=SQL_files[1], table="Sound_Acquisition")

df <- vector("list", length(SQL_files))
for (i in seq_along(SQL_files)) {
  df[[i]] <- dur.df(SQL=SQL_files[i], table="Sound_Acquisition")
}
df <- do.call("rbind", df)  
`

Comment: I recommend to try the proposal from @G. Grothendieck.